# Use of a three wire load cell

Tags: analog, texas-instruments, load-cell

I am currently doing a project which requires the measurement of forces on a surface and to achieve this we are using 3 wire load cells.

The problem that I am running into is no matter how I orient the load cells in a circuit, I cannot seem to notice a notable difference or consistency in voltage supplied to the analog input of my board. I have most recently tried a Wheatstone Bridge layout which I found online. It seems as though the voltages measured through the circuit are always consistent, regardless of what I put on them.

I have achieved success in an online implementation with an Arduino Library, however I had to be using a Arduino board and I do not have this luxury. In my project we are using the CC3220SF Launchpad XL by TI for its wireless communication abilities in another portion of the project.

Does anyone have any ideas which may be able to help me achieve some sort of a measurable reading with these load cells?

Comment: #Derek G, Load cell Wheatstone bridge output is typically very small, of the order of ***millivolts***. So usually a high resolution ADC, such as 12 bit HX711 is used to amplify the say 1~5 mV signal. Let @tlfong01 know if you wish to know more details.

Comment: @tlfong01, I have recently discovered that these load cells that I have are deemed "half-bridge." Could part of my error be that most internet suggested implementations are for 4 load cells and these are half-bridge? Or do you still believe that the lack of a voltage amplifier is the reason for my lack of results?